# Copy data cell down or up

Tags: vba, excel

I am a noob in vba. However, I would like to implement the following use case to make my cooperate life a lot of easier.
I have the following data:
[image]

I would like to copy the first row down until I hit a filled field, the second row also down until I hit a filled field, the third row up and down and the 4th row up.

This is how I would like to have my result sheet should look like.

[image]
Any recommendation how to implement this use case in vba?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: while saying "row" did you mean "column"? I could not understand how you want to copy first row down until you hit a not empty cell.

Comment: A "before" view would really help...

Comment: Without vba, you can select a range from the active cell until the first cell up or down by holding pressed Shift, then End followed by Up or Down arrow. Maybe this helps already.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I just added the view.

Comment: @Dubison Please have a look at my before view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try this one? This routine is assuming column G as main start point and checks if column A,B,C,D is empty or not in the same row and fill it up accordingly.

```
Sub ASD()
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Range("G:G")
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        If c.Offset(0, -3).Value = "" Then
            c.Offset(0, -3).Value = c.Offset(0, -3).End(xlDown).Value
        End If
        If c.Offset(0, -4).Value = "" Then
            c.Offset(0, -4).Value = c.Offset(0, -4).End(xlUp).Value
        End If
        If c.Offset(0, -5).Value = "" Then
            c.Offset(0, -5).Value = c.Offset(0, -5).End(xlUp).Value
        End If
        If c.Offset(0, -6).Value = "" Then
            c.Offset(0, -6).Value = c.Offset(0, -6).End(xlUp).Value
        End If
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Only problem is it do not do anything if the reference cell is empty in the column G. I think you don't need that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help.

It will run on your current selection

Copy the whole code into a module, run the fill_down() to fill down, fill_up() to fill up.

```
'======================
'******Filling*********
'======================
Sub fill_up()
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C"
End Sub

Sub fill_down()
    Call copy_last(Selection)
    Call filling
End Sub

Function copy_last(r As range)
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim x As Double
    Dim arr_size As Double

    arr = r
    arr_size = UBound(arr, 1)

    For x = arr_size To 1 Step -1
        If Not isempty(arr(x, 1)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    r(r.Row, 1) = arr(x, 1)

End Function

Function filling()
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End Function
'=======================
'******End filling******
'=======================
```